# what are the minimum permissions required for user to execute lync cmdlets in powershell

Tags: powershell, permissions, lync

I have a .net application from which i am managing Lync server. I used the cmdlets Get-CsUser, Get-Nonscientific, Grant-Cs, Set-CsUser, Move-CsUser, Enable-CsUser, Disable-CsUser, Set-CsClientPin. For this to work I have assigned group RTCUniversalServerAdmins and CSAdministrator.
can I minimise these permissions on user as it is holding higher privileges?
or any one has a document that will explain which cmdlets required which permission?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen these links:

**Lync2013:**

[Group membership requirements for Lync Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj204623(v=ocs.15).aspx)

and

[Planning for role-based access control in Lync Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg425917(v=ocs.15).aspx)

**Skype For Business:**

[Windows PowerShell and Skype for Business Server 2015 management tools](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481130.aspx)

and

[Role-based access control (RBAC) for Skype for Business Server 2015](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dn481134.aspx)

It looks like it's all modeled around the "Role-Based Access Control" concept in Lync.